# Change chmod of dir from volume

Tags: nginx, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to run CakePHP 2 app inside of a container. I have everything setup and PHP works properly but have one problem: /var/www/app/tmp has incorrect write permissions. This directory is loaded from volume

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you already take a look at the CakePHP2.0 docs? Maybe this is usefull:

One common issue is that the app/tmp directories and subdirectories must be writable both by the web server and the command line user. On a UNIX system, if your web server user is different from your command line user, you can run the following commands just once in your project to ensure that permissions will be setup properly:

```
HTTPDUSER=`ps aux | grep -E '[a]pache|[h]ttpd|[_]www|[w]ww-data|[n]ginx' | grep -v root | head -1 | cut -d\  -f1`
setfacl -R -m u:${HTTPDUSER}:rwx app/tmp
setfacl -R -d -m u:${HTTPDUSER}:rwx app/tmp
```

Source: https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation.html#permissions

Comment: In a container sense there is no command line user. Only root exists in containers. This has to do with the actual overlay process.

Answer (score 0):

This happens a lot if you're running PHP via a container passthrough. In this scenario, you are passing a directory through to the application with pre-defined permissions. What you'll need to do is periodically make sure permissions are being updated to the webserver from the container. Let's say your container is called web

docker exec web chown -R www-data /var/www/html

(/var/www/html being replaced with wherever your code resides)

For Example. This will make it work perfectly fine in the container, but may actually cause issues accessing the data from the host OS if you're using Linux. I had this issue several times with Laravel and PHP using a volume passthrough from the host, since the volume's files themselves are updated to a userID the host OS doesn't have.